# How do I use gmail mailbox with custom domain?

Tags: mx-record, gmail, godaddy

So I have a mydomain.com registered in my name with godaddy.

There's also Gmail which we all love.

I would like to set up myfirstname@mydomain.com to be my email. Godaddy has an email solution, but it's ugly, slow and forwarding is messy.

I would like to set up an MX record which would point to Google servers so that everything sent to myfirstname@mydomain.com gets into my myfirstname.mylastname@gmail.com inbox.

Finding a list of Google's MX records [is easy](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33915?hl=en). However, everything I find tells me how to set it up for G-suite.

I'm puzzled now - is it that Gmail doesn't allow you to do this? What needs to get configured on Gmail side so that it would know that myfirstname@mydomain.com needs to get to my @gmail.com mailbox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, Google doesn't allow this directly unless you use GSuite. However, you can send and receive mail from an another address through Gmail as long as it has an existing POP3 or IMAP account from Settings | Accounts and Import | Send mail as: and Check email from other accounts:. Set up a mailbox using Godaddy and it will still get all the benefits of Gmail.